# iTerm new window starts minimized?

Tags: iterm

For some reason, whenever I start iTerm or press CMD+N, it starts small in the top left corner, but instantly minimizes to my dock

Is there a config that could be causing this?

Where should I look for commands that execute on iTerm start? Thinking maybe one of my coworkers pranked me??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

- In Preferences under Profiles, select the default profile.
- In the Window tab in the "Settings for New Window" section, uncheck "Hide after opening."